# In Angular why does app.module.ts run before the completion of main.ts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need variables to set in my main.ts file before my app.module.ts runs. Is there any reason why this is not the default order? My understanding was that main.ts runs first in Angular and then bootstraps the AppModule.

Example of my situation.

**main.ts**

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { environmentLoader as environmentLoaderPromise } from './environments/environmentLoader';

environmentLoaderPromise.then(env => {
  if (env.production) {
      enableProdMode();
  }

  environment.hosturl = env.hosturl;
  console.log('1')
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  console.log('2')
})
```

Then at the top of my app.module.ts file I have a console.log after all the imports to console.log('3').

The console results in:

3
1
2

How can I make sure that my main.ts is done updating my env var before running the app.module.ts?

app.module.ts below

```js
import { IssuerService } from './issuer.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import { CustomCompModule } from './customcomp/customcomp.module';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './pages/layout/layout.component';

import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './http.interceptor';

import {
  MatIconModule,
} from '@angular/material/icon';

import { MsalModule, MsalRedirectComponent, MsalGuard, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular'; // Import MsalInterceptor
import { InteractionType, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE ') > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

// Import env vars
import { environment } from "./../environments/environment";

console.log('3')
console.log('Var that isnt loaded   ' + environment.redirecturi)

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    // REMOVED in Angular 15 1/4/23 FlexLayoutModule,
    // MSAL AmplifyAuthenticatorModule,
    BrowserModule,
    PagesModule,
    CustomCompModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot( new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: environment.clientid,
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + environment.tenantid,
        redirectUri: environment.redirecturi
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE,
      }
    }), {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
      authRequest: {
        scopes: ['user.read']
        }
    }, {
      interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect, // MSAL Interceptor Configuration
      protectedResourceMap: new Map([ 
          [environment.scopeserver, [environment.scopeapi]]
      ])
    })
  ],
  providers: [    
    {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MsalInterceptor,
    multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    MsalGuard,
    IssuerService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent] // MsalRedirectComponent bootstrapped here
})


export class AppModule {

 }
```

Comment: Your code is asynchronous. The Promise will resolve when it resolves, and meanwhile other stuff keeps going.

Comment: @Pointy thank you for your response -- is there anyway to make sure the line with the environment variable is complete before the next line goes?

Comment: Can you show app.module? The thing is imported so stuff does get processed at that point.

Comment: @Pointy I added the file, you will see what I am trying to do. I need the env vars loaded in order to use them in my app.module.ts

Comment: its because you imported it in your main.ts

Comment: I get this answered the overall question but it does not solve my problem. How can I make sure that environment.hosturl = env.hosturl; is set before angular.module.ts runs.

Comment: Thing is, your implementation is probably wrong. If you need to set stuff here, do it within a mechanism that you control like a function or a provider so you can trigger it before boot, but after import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's running in the correct order, because your `console.log` inside the `app.module.ts` is in the outer file scope, so once you import it, the console logs will run. Imagine the following sequence (the console output is on comments)

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
// 3
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { environmentLoader as environmentLoaderPromise } from './environments/environmentLoader';

environmentLoaderPromise.then(env => {
  if (env.production) {
      enableProdMode();
  }

  environment.hosturl = env.hosturl;
  console.log('1')
  // 1
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
  console.log('2')
  // 2
})
```

Comment: I get this answered the overall question but it does not solve my problem. How can I make sure that environment.hosturl = env.hosturl; is set before angular.module.ts runs.

Comment: @user68288 you have to wait for the Promise to resolve by using `.then()`

Comment: @Pointy sorry for my ignorance but where would that fit in here?

Comment: You'd have to export the promise from "main" and then wait for it where it's used. Or, export the function that starts the asynchronous process and returns the Promise, so you can call the function from the "app.module" code. You cannot make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.

Comment: @user68288 have you looked at using an app initializer to set your environment value?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor I did look into but I also couldn't get that to work. I am still very new to Angular and really having trouble here, if not for SAML using env vars in the module.ts I would be running

Comment: @user68288 have you considered setting your environment server-side before it even gets to Angular? We take this approach to set different environment values at runtime. Email me at alsoicode@gmail.com if you'd like me to walk you through how to do that

Comment: Actually, the title of your question is "In Angular why does app.module.ts run before the completion of main.ts?", and this answers why.

Comment: @EliasSoares I would say yes, and the answers should be upvoted and marked as correct. I was just asking what he/she had tried to help.